# C# regex repeating group of the digit in pattern

Tags: c#, regex

i use regex pattern

```
    pattern = "ID\\d+.*?ID\\d+";
    input="ID1...sometxt1...ID1...sometxt2...ID3...sometxt3...ID50"
    input=Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
    Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Output will = "...sometxt2..."
but i need Output
...sometxt2...ID3...sometxt3...ID50,

i need that regex find groups with equal digit after ID. ID3 != ID50, this group must remain, ID1==ID1 - this group must be replaced

Thank!

Comment: Perhaps, use `pattern = @"\bID(\d+).*?\bID\1\b"` and `var res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");`

Comment: Thank! back reference is good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace the whole substrings from `ID` having the same digits after them, you need to use a capturing group with a backreference:

```
var pattern = @"\bID(\d+).*?\bID\1\b";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbID(%5Cd%2B).*%3F%5CbID%5C1%5Cb&i=ID1...sometxt1...ID1...sometxt2...ID3...sometxt3...ID50&r=)

**Explanation:**

- `\bID` - a whole word "ID"
- `(\d+)` - one or more digits captured into Group 1
- `.*?` - any characters but a newline, as few as possible up to the closest
- `\bID` - whole word "ID" followed with....
- `\1` - backreference to the matched digits in Group 1
- `\b` - followed with a word boundary (so that we do not match `10` if we have `1` in Group 1).

Note that you will need `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier if you have newline characters in your input strings.

Also, do not forget to assign the replacement result to a variable:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
```